# Static class to access Session

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have class which has all session variables I use, Can you please let me know whether it's thread safe.

```
    public static class AppSession
    {
        private const string UserIdKey = "UserId";
        public static int UserId 
        {
           get { return GetSession<int>(UserIdKey); }
           set { SetSession(UserIdKey, value); }
        }

       private static T GetSession<T>(string key)
       {
           var currentSession = HttpContext.Current.Session;

           if (currentSession == null) return default(T);

           if (currentSession[key] != null)
           return (T) currentSession[key];

           return default(T);
    }
}
```

While accessing the property AppSession.UserId will it be thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Each request has its own session, and session is thread safe, becasue:

"the session state module implements a reader/writer locking mechanism and queues the access to state values. A page that has session-state write access will hold a writer lock on the session until the request terminates."

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396